# Initialisation of device_id in CocoaLibSpotify

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, spotify, cocoalibspotify-2.0

Our app uses Spotify Wrapper CocoaSpotifyLib. We have been rejected by Apple's MFI team because the spotify library tries to access the device_id

We have searched inside the CocoaLibSpotify xcode project and found that there is a declaration like this in the api.h file.

```
  const char *device_id;
```

When we try commenting this line and run the app, it crashes.

We could not find the implementation or initialization of this const char anywhere into the CocoaLibSpotify xcode project. 
All the other declarations used in the same structure are initialized except for the device_id

```
typedef struct sp_session_config
```

We are unable to get any hint from the Spotify documentation about the device_id.
According to Spotify they have changed the method to fetch device udid as per apple's review guidelines.

But then our question is what is that they are using to fetch device_id and where exactly the initialization of this device_id happens.

Comment: Is it literally device_id? I.e., does Apple's email mention that? If so, it's a false positive — the underlying library has a symbol called that which isn't related to Apple's stuff. If, on the other hand, it's talking about the device UDID, simply update to the latest version of CocoaLibSpotify (2.4.5), which fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the response. Below are the answers to your questions -

- The crash report states below error related to Device ID

  2013-10-31 15:43:54 -0700 muzik[297]  *** Assertion failure in NSString* base::deviceIdFromKeychain()(), /Users/spotify-buildagent/buildAgent/work/1e0ce8a77adfb2dc/client/base/_apple/_ios/os_ios.mm:287
  2013-10-31 15:43:54 -0700 muzik[297]**   Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: *`'Keychain error when fetching device ID, nonrecoverable'**`
- As per your earlier suggestion in other stackflow post now we are storing all the credentials in `NSUserDefaults`.
- Currently we are using Use `iOS Library  libspotify 12.1.64 for iOS` from the link https://github.com/spotify/cocoalibspotify
- Could you please suggest if we are using the right library. Also suggest the latest iOS Library which is updated in 2.4.5 release

Thank you for your support